# How to send latitude and longitude of a Google Maps marker to Firebase - android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create an Online Shopping App. I have already added a MapActivity and the capability of adding markers on the map when the User longclicks on a spot. And I want to send the User's marker's latitude and longitude to firebase to store on the real-time database.

```
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // First check if myMarker is null
            if (myMarker == null) {

                // Marker was not set yet. Add marker:
                myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title("Your marker title")
                        .snippet("Your marker snippet"));
                LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude,myMarker.getPosition().longitude);
            } else {

                // Marker already exists, just update it's position
                myMarker.setPosition(latLng);
                LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude,myMarker.getPosition().longitude);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Firestore` or `Realtime Database`?

Comment: @GauravMall a marker variable. It's globally declared.

Comment: @GauravMall and it's Realtime database mate

Comment: So your receiving the Longitude and Latitude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a `Reference` to `locations`

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstace().getRef().child("locations");
```

Here you get the location as a `LatLng`:

```
LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude, myMarker.getPosition().longitude);
```

Then you will store it in your database:

```
myRef.child("your_location").child("Latitude").set(myLatLng.getLatitute); 
myRef.child("your_location").child("Longitude").set(myLatLng.getLongitude);
```

To retrieve the information basically do:

```
myRef.child("your_location").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double latitude = dataSnapShot.getValue("Latitude", Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapShot.getValue("Longitude", Double.class);
        LatLng retrievedLang = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadLocation:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
})
```

Comment: Do I have to insert anymore code to upload the location to the database mate? Or is this all?

Comment: This is it, It's simple. You just store them as simple values.

Comment: @GauravMall firebase stores the value of longitude and latitude in Long format so you need to provide long

Comment: I store them as double values for more accuracy, does that affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't remember about Java syntax, so forgive me if there is some odd syntax. But the logic should be like this.

```
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        if (myMarker == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("myDatabase/someDirectory");

        MyMapPoint point = new MyMapPoint();
        point = new Point(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
        usersRef.setValueAsync(point);
    }
```

MyMapPoint is a data class. It should be look like this.

```
class MyMapPoint(){
     String selectedLat, selectedLong;

     MyMapPoint(Long lat, Long long){
         selectedLat = lat;
         selectedLong = long;
     }
}
```